# Function which would get the next `n` slots from the current time

Tags: python, datetime, interview-questions

I have attended an interview recently and my coding got rejected by the panel. I am new to Python and is mentioning my code below. Please help me improve the code quality or any bug:

Question: Given weekly slot availability and current time, return the very next 'n' available slots. Function I have implemented are `get_next_n_slots(week_config, current_time, n=10)` and `isTheWeekListEmpty(week_config)`

```
# from datetime import
from datetime import timedelta
def get_next_n_slots(week_config, current_time, n=10):
 next_n_slots = []
 nextNInput = 0
 format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

 isFirstTime = True
 i = 0

 if (isTheWeekListEmpty(week_config)):
    return next_n_slots

 while nextNInput < 10:
    for days in week_config:
        if (nextNInput + i) >= 10:
            break;
        for slot in days:
            nextNInput += 1
            startArray = slot["start_time"].split(':')
            endArray = slot["end_time"].split(':')
            if isFirstTime:
                if  current_time.hour >= int(startArray[0]) and current_time.minute >= int(startArray[1]):
                    current_time = current_time + timedelta(days=1)
                current_time = current_time + timedelta(hours=(current_time.hour * -1) )
                current_time = current_time + timedelta(minutes=(current_time.minute * -1))
                isFirstTime = False

            result = {}
            start = current_time + timedelta(hours=int(startArray[0])) + timedelta(minutes=int(startArray[1]))
            end = current_time + timedelta(hours=int(endArray[0])) + timedelta(minutes=int(endArray[1]))
            if start >= end:         #assuming atleast take 1 minute to complete the slot
                end = end + timedelta(days=1)
            result["start_time"] = start.strftime(format)
            result["end_time"] = end.strftime(format)
            next_n_slots.append(result)
            print(result)
            if nextNInput >= 10:
                break;

        current_time = current_time + timedelta(days=1)

return next_n_slots

def isTheWeekListEmpty(week_config):
 count = 0
 for day in week_config:
    if (len(day) == 0):
        count += 1
    else: return False

 if count == 7:
    return True
 else: False;

INP_1 = [
[  # Monday
    {"start_time": "06:00", "end_time": "06:30"},
    {"start_time": "06:30", "end_time": "07:00"},
    {"start_time": "07:00", "end_time": "07:30"},
    {"start_time": "07:30", "end_time": "08:00"}
], [  # Tuesday
], [  # Wednesday
    {"start_time": "06:00", "end_time": "06:30"},
    {"start_time": "06:30", "end_time": "07:00"},
    {"start_time": "07:00", "end_time": "07:30"},
    {"start_time": "07:30", "end_time": "08:00"}
], [  # Thursday
    {"start_time": "09:00", "end_time": "09:30"},
    {"start_time": "09:30", "end_time": "10:00"},
    {"start_time": "10:00", "end_time": "10:30"},
    {"start_time": "10:30", "end_time": "11:00"}
], [  # Friday
], [  # Saturday
], [  # Sunday
]
]

OUT_1 = [
{"start_time": "2017-01-02 06:00:00", "end_time": "2017-01-02 
06:30:00"},
{"start_time": "2017-01-02 06:30:00", "end_time": "2017-01-02 
07:00:00"},
{"start_time": "2017-01-02 07:00:00", "end_time": "2017-01-02 
07:30:00"},
{"start_time": "2017-01-02 07:30:00", "end_time": "2017-01-02 
08:00:00"},
{"start_time": "2017-01-04 06:00:00", "end_time": "2017-01-04 
06:30:00"},
{"start_time": "2017-01-04 06:30:00", "end_time": "2017-01-04 
07:00:00"},
{"start_time": "2017-01-04 07:00:00", "end_time": "2017-01-04 
07:30:00"},
{"start_time": "2017-01-04 07:30:00", "end_time": "2017-01-04 08:00:00"},
{"start_time": "2017-01-05 09:00:00", "end_time": "2017-01-05 09:30:00"},
{"start_time": "2017-01-05 09:30:00", "end_time": "2017-01-05 10:00:00"}
]

INP_2 = [
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[],
[]
]

OUT_2 = []

INP_3 = [
 [  # Monday
    {"start_time": "06:00", "end_time": "06:30"},
    {"start_time": "06:30", "end_time": "07:00"},
], [  # Tuesday
    {"start_time": "06:00", "end_time": "06:30"},
    {"start_time": "07:00", "end_time": "07:30"},
    {"start_time": "07:30", "end_time": "07:45"}
], [  # Wednesday
], [  # Thursday
    {"start_time": "09:00", "end_time": "10:00"}
], [  # Friday
], [  # Saturday
], [  # Sunday
]
]

OUT_3 = [
{"start_time": "2017-01-02 06:00:00", "end_time": "2017-01-02 06:30:00"},
{"start_time": "2017-01-02 06:30:00", "end_time": "2017-01-02 07:00:00"},
{"start_time": "2017-01-03 06:00:00", "end_time": "2017-01-03 06:30:00"},
{"start_time": "2017-01-03 07:00:00", "end_time": "2017-01-03 07:30:00"},
{"start_time": "2017-01-03 07:30:00", "end_time": "2017-01-03 07:45:00"},
{"start_time": "2017-01-05 09:00:00", "end_time": "2017-01-05 10:00:00"},
{"start_time": "2017-01-09 06:00:00", "end_time": "2017-01-09 06:30:00"},
{"start_time": "2017-01-09 06:30:00", "end_time": "2017-01-09 07:00:00"},
{"start_time": "2017-01-10 06:00:00", "end_time": "2017-01-10 06:30:00"},
{"start_time": "2017-01-10 07:00:00", "end_time": "2017-01-10 07:30:00"}
]

INP_4 = [
[# Monday
    {"start_time": "21:30", "end_time": "06:30"}],[],
[# Tuesday
    {"start_time": "01:00", "end_time": "00:00"}],
[],[],[],[]
]

OUT_4 = [{'start_time': '2017-01-01 21:30:00', 'end_time': '2017-01-02 06:30:00'},
     {'start_time': '2017-01-03 01:00:00', 'end_time': '2017-01-04 00:00:00'},
     {'start_time': '2017-01-08 21:30:00', 'end_time': '2017-01-09 06:30:00'},
     {'start_time': '2017-01-10 01:00:00', 'end_time': '2017-01-11 00:00:00'},
     {'start_time': '2017-01-15 21:30:00', 'end_time': '2017-01-16 06:30:00'},
     {'start_time': '2017-01-17 01:00:00', 'end_time': '2017-01-18 00:00:00'},
     {'start_time': '2017-01-22 21:30:00', 'end_time': '2017-01-23 06:30:00'},
     {'start_time': '2017-01-24 01:00:00', 'end_time': '2017-01-25 00:00:00'},
     {'start_time': '2017-01-29 21:30:00', 'end_time': '2017-01-30 06:30:00'},
     {'start_time': '2017-01-31 01:00:00', 'end_time': '2017-02-01 00:00:00'}
     ]

INP_5 = [[],
[# Tuesday
    {"start_time": "21:30", "end_time": "22:30"}],[],[],[],[],[]
]

OUT_5 = [{"start_time": "2017-01-02 21:30:00", "end_time": "2017-01-02 22:30:00"},
     {"start_time": "2017-01-09 21:30:00", "end_time": "2017-01-09 22:30:00"},
     {'start_time': '2017-01-16 21:30:00', 'end_time': '2017-01-16 22:30:00'},
     {'start_time': '2017-01-23 21:30:00', 'end_time': '2017-01-23 22:30:00'},
     {'start_time': '2017-01-30 21:30:00', 'end_time': '2017-01-30 22:30:00'},
     {'start_time': '2017-02-06 21:30:00', 'end_time': '2017-02-06 22:30:00'},
     {'start_time': '2017-02-13 21:30:00', 'end_time': '2017-02-13 22:30:00'},
     {'start_time': '2017-02-20 21:30:00', 'end_time': '2017-02-20 22:30:00'},
     {'start_time': '2017-02-27 21:30:00', 'end_time': '2017-02-27 22:30:00'},
     {'start_time': '2017-03-06 21:30:00', 'end_time': '2017-03-06 22:30:00'}
     ]

INP_6 = [[],[],[],[],[],[],
     [#Sunday
         {"start_time": "21:30", "end_time": "21:30"}]
     ]

OUT_6 = [{'start_time': '2017-01-07 21:30:00', 'end_time': '2017-01-08 21:30:00'},
     {'start_time': '2017-01-14 21:30:00', 'end_time': '2017-01-15 21:30:00'},
     {'start_time': '2017-01-21 21:30:00', 'end_time': '2017-01-22 21:30:00'},
     {'start_time': '2017-01-28 21:30:00', 'end_time': '2017-01-29 21:30:00'},
     {'start_time': '2017-02-04 21:30:00', 'end_time': '2017-02-05 21:30:00'},
     {'start_time': '2017-02-11 21:30:00', 'end_time': '2017-02-12 21:30:00'},
     {'start_time': '2017-02-18 21:30:00', 'end_time': '2017-02-19 21:30:00'},
     {'start_time': '2017-02-25 21:30:00', 'end_time': '2017-02-26 21:30:00'},
     {'start_time': '2017-03-04 21:30:00', 'end_time': '2017-03-05 21:30:00'},
     {'start_time': '2017-03-11 21:30:00', 'end_time': '2017-03-12 21:30:00'}
     ]

SAMPLE_INPUT_OUTPUTS = [
(INP_1, OUT_1),
(INP_2, OUT_2),
(INP_3, OUT_3),
(INP_4, OUT_4),
(INP_5, OUT_5),
(INP_6, OUT_6)
]



"""Test cases are designed to run at 8:30 PM.

3 test cases are provided. All cases are not covered. Make sure you handle the cases that are not covered in the list of test cases.
Expecting more test cases to be written.
"""
import datetime
time_of_run = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 20, 30)  # Sunday
for ip, expected_output in SAMPLE_INPUT_OUTPUTS:
  output = get_next_n_slots(ip, time_of_run)
  assert output == expected_output
  print("----------------")
```

Comment: It is very unclear what problem the code solves. Could you add the actual problem statement?

Comment: They haven't mentioned any other information, but I have updated it with the inferred question.

Comment: The `INP_4` example looks like it is wrong. The comment in the input states that the first slot is on Monday, but it is on Sunday in `OUT_4`. The comment also says that the second slot is on Tuesday, when there is clearly a day without slots between the two (and there is obviously no day between Monday and Tuesday in a normal week).

Comment: I tried reviewing this again today and the problem doesn't seem well specified. My understanding would be that you misunderstood the problem. I think your input should've been a calendar, you would've had to find the free time slots and return them, otherwise there really isn't a problem to solve. If you receive an array of `m` time slots, all you would need to do is pick the first `n`. I'll vote to close this question.